# How to append elements to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do the equivalent to adding elements in a python list recursively in Numpy, As in the following code

```
matrix = open('workfile', 'w')
A = []
for row in matrix:
    A.append(row)

print A
```

I have tried the following:

```
matrix = open('workfile', 'w')
A = np.array([])
for row in matrix:
    A = numpy.append(row)

print A
```

It does not return the desired output, as in the list.

Edit this is the sample code:

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('file.mat')
var1 = mat['data1']
A = np.array([])
for row in var1:
    np.append(A, row)

print A
```

This is just the simplest case of what I want to do, but there is more data processing in the loop, I am putting it this way so the example is clear.

Comment: That looks more *iteratively* than *recursively* to me... also... have you looked at just using `np.loadtxt` to load data from files?

Comment: For what it's worth, none of your question has anything to do with recursion.  You're just using looping, which is different from recursion.  Beyond that, there's a lot of goofiness in your second example.  You're trying to put strings of potentially arbitrary length into a Numpy array.

Comment: the variable "matrix" means that the file only contains numbers

Comment: A file containing only numbers can be loaded with `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt`. Appending to a NumPy array is slow. Avoid doing this if you can.

Comment: This is only an example, I know how to load files to numpy arrays and I know that it is better, the question is how to append values to numpy arrays in cases where I have to iterate as in a for loop.

Comment: @user3025898 then build a `list`/`tuple` from the iterable if you can first? Put simply, if your data will fit in memory, use .loadtxt/.genfromtxt and then drop your not interested in items, otherwise, have a function return either a list, or yield data to pre-select and use np.fromiter if you can.

Comment: I want to skip the numpy to list, list to numpy step since the transformation sometimes formats wrongly the data. I think the function fromiter is more on the lines on what I am looking for.

Comment: Adding my 2c. Don't forget that appending something to a numpy array doesn't change it in place, it makes a complete copy. It would be faster to build a python list and convert it into an array when you're done appending items. In case you have some heavy memory restrictions, you might consider arrays from the `array` module. They are dynamic static typed arrays.

Comment: If `var1` comes from a `loadmat` isn't already an array (or numpy matrix)?  Can't you use vector operations to transform it into a new numpy array?  Or if you must iterate use the `A[i,:] = fn(var1[i,:])` idiom.?

Comment: `np.append` is just a fancy wrapper around `np.concatenate`.  It creates a new array by concatenating the old array and new line.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to pass the array, A, to Numpy.

```
matrix = open('workfile', 'w')
A = np.array([])
for row in matrix:
    A = numpy.append(A, row)

print A
```

However, loading from the files directly is probably a nicer solution.

Comment: Please see the sample code provided, running your code returns an empty array []

Comment: Are you sure your input file is begin read correctly / has appropriate data?

    for i in range(5):
        np.append(A, i)
Gives:
array([ 0.])
array([ 1.])
array([ 2.])
array([ 3.])
array([ 4.])

So I believe this works.

Comment: this is the program I am running `import numpy as np
A = np.array([])
for i in range(5):
    np.append(A, i)

print A` it returns []

Comment: Thanks it is working now. Is there a way to save i as either a column or a as a row in your program?

Comment: @user3025898 Use the [`axis` keyword argument for `numpy.append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). It will require getting the axes aligned with a transpose, i.e. `A = numpy.append(A, row.T, axis=1)`