# How to append items to array of object?

Tags: python, arrays, append

I've got a problem when using array of object:
For example, I have:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype = object)
```

Now I want to append a row to array a:

```
b = np.array([[10, 11, 12, 13]], dtype = object)
```

After appending, the output I want is:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]], dtype = object)
```

So, can anyone please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append elements to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943887/how-to-append-elements-to-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to append a list of size 4 to an array of lists of size 3?

Comment: Why are you using an array to begin with, if you are going to use `dtype=object`?

Comment: I actually use MATLAB. In MATLAB i have the cell array, which can show [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]. So i want to translate it to python. I am not sure that dtype=object is exact, so can anyone please help me?

Comment: Just use a regular `list` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try numpy.append method. Example below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype = object)
b=np.append(a,[[11,12,13]], axis=0)
print (b)
```

Comment: Normally this would be the correct solution, however in the question `b` has 4 elements so this doesn't work.

Comment: I actually use MATLAB. In MATLAB i have the cell array, which can show [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]. So i want to translate it to python. I am not sure that dtype=object is exact, so can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the dimensions of both of your arrays before appending

you can use `print(myArray.shape)` to get dimensions

Here you want to append a row of dimensions (1,4) to an array (3,3)

It won't work as desired

So i think you first have to augment the shape of your array

for example :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], dtype = object)

a= np.concatenate((a,np.zeros((3,1))),axis = 1)
# now you have a (3,4) array thus you can easily add a (1,4) row
#Point 1

b = np.array([[10,11,12,13]])

a = np.concatenate((a,b))
#Point 2
```

> i used `np.concatenate` function here but you can obviously use other functions

**OUTPUTS**

```
#Point 1 

[[1 2 3 0.0]
 [4 5 6 0.0]
 [7 8 9 0.0]]

#Point 2

[[1 2 3 0.0]
 [4 5 6 0.0]
 [7 8 9 0.0]
 [10 11 12 13]]
```